# Cocoapods no integrate in Pod file

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

So I have multiple projects all of which use cocoapods. For one of the projects we need to use the `--no-integrate` flag I was wondering can we move this declaration to the podfile some how so we don't have to remember the difference every time we go into that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the CocoaPods 1.0 betas, you can use:

```
install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false
```

In your Podfile.

Comment: Updated my answer for the CocoaPods 1.0 betas. There is no way pre 1.0 though.